# LCD showing weird characters when using two 1-wire temperature sensors

Tags: lcd, 1-wire

I have a sketch to display a temperature obtained from 1-wire DS18B20 sensors. The sketch works fine, however when I connect two sensors to my board, the text on the LCD displays gets corrupted (### and other symbols shown instead of a temperature).

I have tried plugging each of the two DS18B20 sensors individually and it works with both of them, the problem shows only when I use both at the same time. I am connecting them both with black to ground, red to 5V and white to Dx and to 5V via a 4.7 kOhm pull-up resistor.

I have little idea how to check what is wrong - is it some kind of interference, insufficient voltage, or a SW problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more searching I have found [Arduino forum topic LCD text corrupts after Arduino runs for length of time](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?PHPSESSID=kpntcnv2f3dq544iuh5inrl404&topic=86731.msg650003#msg650003). I have followed [this advice](http://forum.arduino.cc/index.php?PHPSESSID=j4imm6sr0dbrnas4pp1unc8ae5&topic=86731.msg653008#msg653008):

> In particular, try running the LCD ground wire directly to a ground pin on the Arduino (not to the breadboard) and keep it short.

This seemed to solve the issue, therefore it was likely some kind of interference on the ground wiring. (Before this, the ground to the LCD went trought the breadboard power bus).